# Integration where constant variables is input and plot function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm doing a python project where I need to calculate the velocity of a motorboat and the position of it.
The formula for velocity is **v = v0*e^-bt/m** and position is **p = (m*v0/b)*(1-e^-bt/m)** where b is given as 14 while m(mass) and v0(initial velocity) need to be input by the user. After all this, I also need to plot the function.

The program requirements are :

1. Request the user input for initial velocity 0 and mass of a motorboat .
2. Set up sufficient discrete/grid points along the cross-sectional
   domain, t = [0,21].( The final value is specified as 21 because we
   want 20 to be included as well)
3. Compute the velocity of the boat based on Equation (1) and the position of the boat based on Equation (2)
4. Plot the velocity and position of the boat on the same axis.
5. Set up suitable legend, title, axis-label, and line colour in your graph.
6. Output the value of velocity and position.

So far I managed to code only this:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return v0*math.exp(-b*t/m) #v = intial velocity, b = constant, t = time, m = mass

def p(t):
    return (m*v)/b*(1-math.exp(-b*t/m))#v = intial velocity, b = constant, t = time, m = mass

b = int(14)
v0 = float(input("What is the initial velocity of the motorboat in m/s? "))
m = float(input("what is the mass of the motorboat in kg? "))
i=[0]

velocity,err = quad(f,0,21)
position,err = quad(p,0,21)
print("The velocity of the boat moving across a lake is ",format(velocity,".2f"),"m/s.")
print("The position of the boat after moving across a lake is ",format(position,".2f"),"m.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes there:

- Velocity is the derivative of the position, not its integral.
- The position is the integral but you are integrating the position itself.
- From the "Set up sufficient discrete/grid points along the cross-sectional domain, t = [0,21]." it seems they would like you to create derivative and integral yourself instead of using numpy's function.

  - Use the definition of the derivative with finite `dt`
  - Use e.g. the rectangle method for integration:
    https://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2015/03/numerical-integration-with-python.html
- Plotting is easy with matplotlib, see:
  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html